# How to use Event ChildMoved without old index and new index

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase to store some data and pull it ordered by date

```
let query = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("entry").
        queryOrderedByChild("time_start")
```

Then I'm listening to the following events on this query:

- `FIRDataEventType.ChildChanged`
- `FIRDataEventType.ChildAdded`
- `FIRDataEventType.ChildMoved`
- `FIRDataEventType.ChildRemoved`

When in the database I will modify the date entry then `FIRDataEventType.ChildMoved` followed by `FIRDataEventType.ChildChanged` is fired but the order on the table doesnt change.

How should I use it to update `tableView` that the order has changed? Is there a "smart" way or I have to do a new call to `...queryOrderedByChild` method?

**UPDATE**

Why anyone needs "minimal example" when there is no failure in code but rather missing a feature for moving content?

e.g. when I'm using Core Data and `NSFetchedResultsController` I have a delegate method `controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?)` which for type `.Move` gives me the old index and new index which then I can use to manipulate the table to remove from old index and insert at new index.

With Firebase all I get is an event called `.ChildMoved` with a snapshot but without information about the "move transformation" e.g. old/new index (position). Thus my question is there another way to update table when data will change in a way that the order has changed?

Comment: It's going to be hard to help with seeing a [minimal complete example of the code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Did you solve this? I think the question is pretty self explanatory, I don't know why the comment above was posted